# shm_open() fails with EINVAL

Tags: shared-memory

```
IPC_SHM_FD = shm_open("/dev/ipc", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

The above fails with `EINVAL` (with or without O_CREAT). File `/dev/ipc` exists.

```
%ls -la
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 251, 0 Apr 25 15:30 /dev/ipc
```

gdb output:

```
Breakpoint 1, ipc_mem_init (min_blk_shift=7) at ipcd.c:335
335         IPC_SHM_FD = shm_open("/dev/ipc", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
(gdb) n
336         if (IPC_SHM_FD == -1) {
(gdb) n
337             perror("shm_open: ");
(gdb) p errno
$1 = 22
(gdb)
```

What is invalid here?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `shm_open`(3):

> For portable use, a shared memory object should be identified by a name of the form /somename; that is, a null-terminated string of up to NAME_MAX (i.e., 255) characters  consisting  of  an initial slash, followed by one or more characters, **none of which are slashes**.

Choose another name.